# Creating a Google doc from Appsheet

Tags: google-appsheet

Can you create a Google doc from Appsheet dynamically ?  It allows you to create a pdf file on a Google drive but not a Google doc . Opening the pdf as a Google doc leads to having two files (pdf and doc) and not what we need.So, can we create a doc with a .gdoc extension thru Appsheet?

Answer (score 0):

[AppSheet's "**Run a task**" feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ptv.png) currently [supports creating files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljQMo.png) like csv, html, json, pdf, xlsx, xml, and ics_calendar. it does not directly support creating Google Docs (.gdoc) files.

To create a Google Docs file, you can use AppSheet's "call a script" feature with Google Apps Script. Write a script in Google Apps Script to create a Google Docs file, and then call this script from AppSheet. For guidance on creating Google Docs via Apps Script, see the Google Developers guide: [Apps Script Guide for Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs).